# How to make shorter (closer) token match more relevant? (edge_ngram)

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram, elasticsearch-query, relevance

I'm getting weird results with edge_ngram tokenizer I'm using for autocomplete. I'm trying to figure out how to make my results more relevant. I copied the [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) from the elasticsearch documentation.

I have documents with the following descriptions:

- "Apples, raw, without skin"
- "Apples, raw, golden delicious, with skin"
- "APPLEBEE'S, chili"
- "Babyfood, fruit, applesauce, junior"

If I search for `apple`, "APPLEBEE'S, chili" will get higher score than "Apples, raw, without skin"

If I search for `apples`, "Babyfood, fruit, applesauce, junior" will get higher score than "Apples, raw, golden delicious, with skin"

**In both cases I would like to have higher score for the more relevant closer/shorter match (ie. when I search for `apple` or `apples`, the result containing the word `apples` should have higher score than `APPLEBEE'S` or `applesauce`.**

My settings are:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

query:

```
"query": {
    "match": {
      "description": {
          "query": "apple", 
          "operator": "and"
        }
    }
}
```

How to get the more relevant results score higher?

Comment: can you share your mapping as well, so we know what analyzer is used on your fields

Comment: I updated the question, but I used the example code for autocomplete from the docs linked above for edgengram tokenizer

Answer (score 3):

This issue is happening due to the length of the matching field known as (dl) in the new BM25 algo(used for scoring), you can easily use the [explain param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/7.9/search-search.html#request-body-search-explain) on your query to understand it in detail

> http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}//_search?explain=true

As your `APPLEBEE'S, chili` is the shortest in length it gets more score, this is the tf score for this doc

```
 {
                                    "value": 0.5344296,
                                    "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "value": 1.0,
                                            "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                                            "details": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": 1.2,
                                            "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                                            "details": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": 0.75,
                                            "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                                            "details": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": 11.0,
                                            "description": "dl, length of field", ---> note this
                                            "details": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": 17.333334,
                                            "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                                            "details": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
```

**Solution**

You need to create another field which uses the `english` analyzer as shown in the [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) example, below is complete example

**Index example**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                },
                "autocomplete_search": {
                    "tokenizer": "lowercase"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 20,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
                "fields": {
                    "english": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "english"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**And index your sample docs**

```
{
    "name" : "Apples, raw, without skin"
}
{
    "name" : "APPLEBEE'S, chili"
}
{
    "name" : "Babyfood, fruit, applesauce, junior"
}
{
    "name" : "Apples, raw, golden delicious, with skin"
}
```

**And search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "apple",
                        "fields": [
                            "name.english",
                            "name"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result, note higher score for docs containing `apple`**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "edgelow",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.6747451,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Apples, raw, without skin"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "edgelow",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 0.60996956,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Apples, raw, golden delicious, with skin"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "edgelow",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.12822598,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "APPLEBEE'S, chili"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "edgelow",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.09446116,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Babyfood, fruit, applesauce, junior"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for the detailed explanation. Is it possible to do this without depending on a language analyzer? This text field can contain words from any language, so I need to find a solution that is not language specific.

Comment: @orszaczky, yes definitely you can use standard analyzer but as it doesn't stem the words(hence apple will not match apple(s)) and to fix this issue, used `english` but this was just for your sample data, if you don't use any language analyzer and use `text` field it will by default use `standard` analyzer which is default and works great in most of the use-cases.

Comment: I'm still looking for a more general solution that is not language specific, where simply a closer (shorter) match `apples` gets higher relevance than a longer match `applesauce` when I search for `apple`. Btw I already upvoted the answer, just hoping to get (or come up with) a better solution

Comment: Or maybe a better example where the shorter match `asdfg` gets higher relevance than the longer match `asdfghjkl` when I search for `asdf`.